# Can a data abstraction use a class as a field, parameter, or return type?

Tags: terminology, object-oriented, abstract-data-types

I think that everyone will agree that the following class achieves *data abstraction* (hiding of its internal representation):

```
class A {
    private List x = new ArrayList();

    public List getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setX(List x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

But could we say the same about the following one, which uses a *class* (instead of an *interface* like in the previous class) as a field type, parameter type, and return type?

```
class B {
    private ArrayList x = new ArrayList();

    public ArrayList getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setX(ArrayList x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/49207/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/142051/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Personally i wouldn't even consider the first one as data abstraction

Comment: You have tagged your question with both [tag:abstract-data-types] and [tag:object-oriented]. That is somewhat confusing because ADT-based data abstraction and object-oriented data abstraction are very different, and in some sense even opposites. You should be clear about which one of the two you mean. See for example [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by [William R. Cook](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/) for a simple explanation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am currently reading Luca Cardelli’s paper *On understanding types, data abstraction, and polymorphism*, which prompted William Cook to write his paper on the subtle distinction between abstract data types and objects. Since I have not started reading William Cook’s paper, I did not want to exclude any possibilities, especially because I feel that the answer is precisely about this distinction. Could you write an answer?

Comment: To be honest, the example might be too simplistic. Especially since OO is all about behavior, and OO-abstraction is behavioral abstraction, but there is no behavior in your example.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I have just read John Reynold’s [*User-Defined Types and Procedural Data Structures as Complementary Approaches to Data Abstraction*](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/john-reynolds/procedural-data-structures.pdf) which is the oldest paper quoted by William Cook on the abstract data type–object distinction and which is shorter. It seems that contrary to abstract data types, objects can only access the representation of a *single* object, which means that my class `A` above defines an abstract data type and my class `B` above defines an object. Do you agree?

Comment: I would argue that neither are objects, because objects are all about behavior, all about what they *do*, and neither of your two pieces of code do anything at all. At the very least, they're not good examples of objects.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds subjective to me.  Data abstraction is not a black-and-white binary property; it is a matter of shades of grey.  Any abstraction hides some information and reveals others.

Another way to put it is that these two classes expose a different amount of functionality and make a different set of promises.  So, what do you want the client to be aware of, and what do you want them to not have to know about?  What future changes do you want to allow yourself to make to the class (without having to change clients), and what future changes are not important to be able to make?  The answers to those questions will determine which of these two implementations you choose.  Each could be a reasonable choice that is consistent with the principle of data abstraction in different circumstances.

Also, remember that abstraction is a means to an end, not a goal in and of itself.

See, e.g., https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/.